# Return type as same as struct golang

Tags: pointers, go, struct

I have a struct :

```
type Race struct {
    Name    string `json:"Name"`
    About   string `json:"About"`
    Health  int    `json:"Health"`
    Attacks []Move `json:"Attacks"`
}
```

and a function that loads the struct:

```
func LoadClass(path string) *Race {
    bytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    jsonClass := &Race{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(bytes, jsonClass)
    //decodes it
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return jsonClass
}
```

is there a way to make `jsonClass` of type `Race` and not `*Race`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a pointer to the variable to Unmarshal and just return the variable.

```
func LoadClass(path string) (race Race) {
    bytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if err = json.Unmarshal(bytes, &race); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: This blows my mind, i didn't know that we can have named return in function declaration

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just return a value of `Race` instead of `*Race`:

```
func LoadClass(path string) Race {

    // read file to []byte

    jsonClass := new(Race)
    _ = json.Unmarshal(bytes, jsonClass)

    // return the value jsonClass points to
    return *jsonClass
}
```